# What are the names of parents of Adrien-Marie Legendre, and their dates of birth and death?

Tags: mathematicians, legendre

What are the full names and dates of birth and of death of the parents of [Adrien-Marie Legendre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adrien-Marie_Legendre)? I couldn't find this information anywhere online. Not even their names. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

MacTutor is a good source for biographies of mathematicians.  Of [Legendre](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Legendre) it begins:

> Adrien-Marie Legendre would perhaps have disliked the fact that this article contains details of his life

It also seems unclear whether he was born in Paris or in Toulouse.

That being said, the genealogy website geneanet has [an entry](https://gw.geneanet.org/geneavendeemili?lang=en&n=legendre&oc=0&p=adrien%20marie) which gives his parents as Adrien LEGENDRE and Marie Anne Charlotte RIFAU.  See also [an excerpt of the correspondence between Stieltjes and Hermite](https://books.google.com/books?id=WdbWpEjLU7sC&pg=PA200&lpg=PA200&dq=%22Marie%20Anne%20Charlotte%20RIFAU%22&source=bl&ots=EN5-rNYg7Q&sig=ACfU3U0dv4DG49vPrXf3AgDqpuLPgvgoVw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjglvKOzuz6AhXcL0QIHStgCkgQ6AF6BAgJEAM#v=onepage&q=%22Marie%20Anne%20Charlotte%20RIFAU%22&f=false) which contains these same names in a footnote.